# Sorting a vector using array version of quick sort

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I'm coding  a simple rendering engine using OpengGL and I wrote a class that manages a particle system. The class creates the particles and pushes them into a vector to be used by a renderer to draw them on screen. I need to order the particles from the farthest to the nearest to the camera (in order to solve problems with alpha blending and depth), so I tried with the following code:

```
void ParticleRenderer::sortParticles(Particle **particles, int low, int high)
{
    if (low >= high)
        return;
    Particle *temp = particles[low];
    while (true)
    {
        while (compareParticles(temp, particles[high]) >= 0 && low < high)
            high--;
        if (low == high)
            break;
        else
            particles[low++] = particles[high];
        while (compareParticles(temp, particles[low]) < 0 && low < high)
            low++;
        if (low == high)
            break;
        else
            particles[high--] = particles[low];
    }
    particles[high] = temp;
    int middle = high;
    sortParticles(particles, low, middle - 1);
    sortParticles(particles, middle + 1, high);
}

double ParticleRenderer::compareParticles(Particle *particle1, Particle *particle2)
{
    return  getCameraDistance(particle1) - getCameraDistance(particle2);
}

double ParticleRenderer::getCameraDistance(Particle *particle)
{
    glm::vec3 distance = mCamera.getPosition() - particle->getPosition();
    return glm::length(distance);
}
```

The following code is used to test the sorting:

```
sortParticles(&mParticles[0], 0, mParticles.size() - 1);

for (Particle *particle : mParticles)
    std::cout << getCameraDistance(particle) << std::endl;
```

What I get on the console are all unsorted particles. Can someone explain why the sorting doesn't work?

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparator?

Comment: @StoryTeller, yes I'm gonna try..but since I'm learning I want to know where I am doing wrong

Comment: @BDL ok, done, thanks

Comment: If you're learning quicksort, why not try it on an array of integers first?  Then when you get that working, the only difference would be to supply a function that tests the order of two items, whether the first item comes before the second.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Done that, my integer array version works. So I must be missing something here.

Comment: Then take the integer version, then templatize it by passing in the type, and overload `operator <`. for that type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't learned about templates yet. I know how to use them, but I'd like to pinpoint my error here. As far as I can see, there should be nothing wrong with the code, but there is.

Comment: @Luca Well, this is a good time to learn what a template is or the concept of a template.  Take the version you claim works with integers, and change all of the `int` declarations to `Particle`.  What is the difference?  The only difference should be that you need to implement  `operator <` for `Particle`.

Comment: @Luca: try to paste a complete, compilable code here. I'm sure that you will get an answer in no time. Just a little thing: if you use this for depth sort, you want to use `mCamera.getPosition().z - particle->getPosition().z` instead of 3D distance.

Comment: Also, as the first comment suggest, what's wrong with just using `std::sort(startParticle, endParticle, [&](const Particle* p1, const Particle* p2) { return getCameraDistace(p1) < getCameraDistance(p2); });`?

Comment: @geza the camera in moving in 3D space, so I need to consider the sum of all three dimensions (what if  I'm looking towards the x axis?)

Comment: In that case, transform particle position into the camera space (`inv(cameraMatrix)*pos`), then use the transformed Z coordinate.

Answer (score -1):

Actually my recursive quicksort was wrong. While testing with a vector of ints I used a slightly different version, in wich the partitioning of the array was performed in another function. This version is flawed since I'm passing to the recursive quicksort (divide and conquer I understand..) the same high and low indices that are used in the algorithm...so I'm passing the same index...hence no sorting.